# how to save the command prompt output to an Microsoft 365 Excel or google spreadsheets (online)

Tags: javascript, typescript, batch-file, scripting, spreadsheet

hello everyone i used a **.bat** file get all devise information and start to data entry it manually in google spreadsheet

[https://github.com/hegazytarek/Device-information](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

but now i want this **.bat** file to import this data to Microsoft 365 Excel sheet or google spreadsheet
every **new run** recoded in **new Row** in same sheet

but i don't want just a code i want to learn how to achieve this thing but really i don't know from where should i start or how could i achieve my target
any help please and thanks for your time

my **.bat** file now can extartct the data in .txt file in the same dir. like this
[image]

my target to save this data in Microsoft 365 Excel sheet or google spreadsheet with the same format
[image]

Comment: Batch is dumb. It can't handle Excel or Word files, just pure text files (`.csv` *is*  a pure text file).

Comment: i don't want from batch something more than get the information , just want to configure what can achieve importing data from the text to the Microsoft 365 Excel sheet or google spreadsheet
i think JS can help me but i don't

Comment: You don't need a batch file to get the information either. You should be able to extract that simple data using WMI in almost any programming language. _You could probably even do it using VBA in Microsoft Excel itself._ I will also add that there seems to be no good reason to store the PC's used memory, so I'd exclude that from my code.

Comment: In addition, you appear to be using WMIC.exe, systeminfo.exe, and powershell.exe to grab the information anyhow. Those are just executable files and have no need to be executed from a batch file. It would probably be more efficient to use powershell.exe to grab all of the information. And please never run systeminfo.exe from a script, it is the least efficient way to get whatever data you are looking for.

Comment: i am so grateful for  u @Compo and this is great information but when i try to do the same batch with PS it ask for administrator to run but the bat file don't ask so choose bat here ,,,, 2nd  i will remove the systeminfo.exe  and check the results

Comment: 3rd do u main "Windows Management Instrumentation" bec i cant understand hoe it help me in my case my problem now to get this data , but i cant export it in Microsoft 365 Excel sheet or google spreadsheet as we u them in work and easy for all the team to work with them but if there is anyway to collect the date from bat or txt file and send it to different computer it could help too

Comment: WMIC.exe, which you are using for some of your commands is translated as Windows Management and Instrumentation Commandline utility. So of course WMI can help you! Also when you run systeminfo.exe it runs a series of WMI queries, then translates the results into its chosen readable format.